# Is there a way to check if RVO was applied?

Tags: c++11

I had this whole story about my frustrating journey to finding out that an unordered map I was returning from a function was not in fact RVO'd even though I was certain it was at an earlier time that it was but irrelevant.

Is there a way to check if RVO is happening in any given function? Or like a list of do's and dont's to follow to get the outcome I desire?

Comment: You check the generated assembly code? I don't think you can request that information from the compiler.

Comment: @Borgleader, not everyone understands assembly :-)...

Comment: @WhiZTiM: not everyone understands C++ either, but here we are

Comment: I would be surprised if there is a *standard* way to check if RVO is happening, since it's implementation-defined when and when it happens and whether it happens at all. @PSkocik's answer is probably the most surefire method. Otherwise, you could look at documentation for specific compilers that you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Create hooks for the lifecycle methods of your class:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{
  A() 
    { std::cout<<"Ctor\n"; } 
  A(const A& o) 
    { std::cout<<"CCtor\n"; } 
  A(A&& o) 
    { std::cout<<"MCtor\n"; } 
  ~A() 
    { std::cout<<"Dtor\n"; } 
private:
  int vl_;
};

A getA(){
  A a;
  return a;
}

int main(){
  A b = getA();
  return 0;
}
```

Now with RVO, b is the same object as `a` in `getA` so you'll only see

```
Ctor
Dtor
```

You can suppress RVO, e.g., by adding an additional return point:

```
 return a;
 return A{a};
```

or moving:

```
return std::move(a);
```

And then you'll see:

```
Ctor
Mctor
Dtor
Dtor
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this on a lower-level? i.e. without changing code?

Answer (score 5):

You can verify that RVO was used in all the places where it's important to you:

```
template<typename T>
struct force_rvo: T {
    force_rvo() {}
    using T::T;
    force_rvo(const force_rvo &);
    force_rvo(force_rvo &&);
};

force_rvo<std::map<int, int>> f() {
    force_rvo<std::map<int, int>> m;
    m[17] = 42;
    return m;
}

int main() {
    auto m = f();
    return m[42];
}
```

The `force_rvo` type pretends to be copyable and movable, otherwise compiler would reject `return m`. But if any of these is actually used, linker will fail and tell you where exactly that happened. The wrapper is zero cost, but requires using it both on caller and implementation sides, which may not be very convenient.